# How to get directory name of shared drive in java in windows operating system

Tags: java, windows, file-io

I have shared file path ex: \\Some-folder\folderName. Using java how can I get directory name? Means whether it is in D/E drive of windows operating system.
Note:- In my case I have not the complete path of the folder/file. Someone shared only a folder with me and my business requirement is to find the directory of the shared folder.

Comment: @notyou I have updated my question it is not duplicate.

Comment: get the *file system roots* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots-- , iterate over them and check which of them is the root of your actual file

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Can you elaborate more ? suppose file is in E:\\demo\test and someone shared test folder with me how can I get from which directory it belongs.

Comment: I think that is quite impossible since you only see the drive letter which is the replacement for the share. You might try to compare the *content* of the share (direct children, not recursive) with the contents of the roots returned by `File.listRoots()` but that's for sure just a wild guess...